# Error Message Unclear: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust

I do not understand the error message I am getting for the following code.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Weak;

struct ThingPool {
    thing_map: HashMap<String, Thing>,
}

impl ThingPool {
    pub fn get(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&Thing> {
        self.thing_map.get(key)
    }
}

struct Thing {
    pool: Weak<RefCell<ThingPool>>,

    key: String,
    parent_key: String,
}

impl Thing {
    pub fn parent(&self) -> Option<&Thing> {
        let pool = &*self
            .pool
            .upgrade()
            .expect("FATAL: ThingPool no longer exists")
            .borrow();

        pool.get(&self.parent_key)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // ...
}
```

I have a recursive data structure of Things, and I am trying to write a method that looks up the parent of a particular Thing in the ThingPool based on its key. The error message I am getting is:

```
  --> src/main.rs:30:9
   |
24 |           let pool = &*self
   |  ______________________-
25 | |             .pool
26 | |             .upgrade()
27 | |             .expect("FATAL: ThingPool no longer exists")
28 | |             .borrow();
   | |_____________________- temporary value created here
29 |
30 |           pool.get(&self.parent_key)
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I understand that I cannot return a reference to a local value, but I do not understand what the local value is in this case. What is the "data owned by the current function"? The value I am returning is a value of the HashMap in the ThingPool. I am not copying the `pool` and therefore the HashMap and therewith the value should not be local to the function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `upgrade().expect("...")`, that creates a new `Rc` that is owned by the current function. When you borrow out of the `Rc`, that reference cannot outlive the `Rc` you just created: when the `Rc` is dropped, it will decrement the reference count, potentially deallocating the pool and leaving any references invalid. Currently, it is dropped when you leave the function, but the function still returns a reference to its contents.

Breaking up the chain of calls helps a little bit.

```rust
pub fn parent(&self) -> Option<&Thing> {
    let pool_rc = self
        .pool
        .upgrade()
        .expect("FATAL: ThingPool no longer exists");
        
    let pool_ref = pool_rc.borrow();

    let parent_ref = pool_ref.get(&self.parent_key);
    
    return parent_ref;
}
```

`pool_rc` is the `Rc` pointer. It doesn't get returned, so it's a local that must be dropped at the end of the function call.

`pool_ref` is a reference to the pool. It doesn't know anything about the reference count, and it's relying on `pool_rc` to increment the count before it starts and decrement the count after it ends.

`parent_ref` is in the same pickle as `pool_ref`. It doesn't know about the reference count, and is relying on `pool_rc` stick around until after `parent_ref` expires so that `pool_rc` does not decrement the reference count while `parent_ref` needs access to the pool.

When you return `parent_ref` you are trying to make it outlive `pool_rc`, which could cause issues.

Here's an example of what could go wrong if this function was allowed:

1. There is some external `Rc` on the pool, so the reference count on the pool is 1.
2. You run `Thing::parent`, returning a reference to an item in the pool, but because the `Rc` to the pool is dropped when the function ends, the reference count on the pool is still 1.
3. That external `Rc` is dropped, taking the refcount to 0 and deallocating the pool.
4. You use the reference returned from `parent`, which refers to the already-deallocated memory.

You might be able to find some solution where you return a `Rc` to the pool alongside the reference to the parent, guaranteeing that it exists. However, I would advocate a different strategy: rather than hiding the fact that there is a pool, explicitly embrace it. Moving the `parent` call into the `ThingPool` makes the ownership dynamics clear.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct ThingPool {
    thing_map: HashMap<String, Thing>,
}

impl ThingPool {
    pub fn get(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&Thing> {
        self.thing_map.get(key)
    }

    pub fn parent(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&Thing> {
        self.get(key).and_then(|thing| self.get(&thing.parent_key))
    }
}

struct Thing {
    key: String,
    parent_key: String,
}
```